# Hide post category name wherever it might be mentioned

Tags: categories

Is there a way to exclude a category name from displaying on any lists of categories a post is in? I want a "silent" category. It exists, posts from it are shown in the loop, but it is not mentioned anywhere in any list of what categories a post is in.

Comment: What's the reason behind this need?  There might be an alternate solution that would work better for you, what you're asking for doesn't seem easily achievable.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can use the `wp_get_object_terms` filter to remove the hidden category from any list that uses default WordPress methods like `wp_get_post_categories()`.

```
add_filter('wp_get_object_terms', 'wpse_remove_unwanted_category', 10, 4);
function wpse_remove_unwanted_category($terms, $object_ids, $taxonomies, $args) {
    // we're only interested in category, if this is another taxonomy
    if ($args['taxonomy'] !== 'category') {
        // return early
        return $terms;
    }

    // 34 and 1509 are ids of categories we want to remove
    $remove_categories = array(34, 1509);
    $filtered_terms = array_filter($terms, function($term) use ($remove_categories) {
        // if term_id is in the array, filter it out (aka remove from array)
        return ( ! in_array($term->term_id, $remove_categories));
    });
    return $filtered_terms;
}
```

However, this filter will remove the unwanted categories from many lists, not only those in the frontend.

Comment: Thank you! I just realized it's actually a custom taxonomy named "portfolio_category". I updated the code where it says 'category' to reflect this but it did not seem to work. Is there anything else I should change?

Comment: What theme are you using? Can you find out if it is using `wp_get_object_terms()` or something else like `get_terms()`?